# Calling a For loop from an onClick button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I believe that this is something to do with global variables, however i am not sure, i think that it is something to do with calling variables from my script.js, can anyone inform me of the correct way to do this?

EDIT AT BOTTOM

I am trying to get a button to create 7 random images, however when i use the loop inside the button nothing happens.

Basically, this works:

```
<script>
function drawCard() {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", imageLocation);
    x.setAttribute("alt", card);
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    var element = document.getElementById("cardArea");
    element.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<script>
function drawHand() {
    var newFull = fullDeck.slice();
    document.write(newFull);
    var k = 0;


    for (k = 0; k < 7; k++) {            
        var randomCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * newFull.length) + 1);

        chosenCard = newFull[randomCard];
        var chosenCardString = String(chosenCard);
        var randomIndex = newFull.indexOf(chosenCard);

        newFull.splice(randomIndex, 1);

        var imageLocation = 'Images/' + chosenCardString.replace(/ /g, '') + '.png';

        var y = document.createElement("IMG");
        y.setAttribute("src", imageLocation);
        y.setAttribute("alt", chosenCard);
        document.body.appendChild(y);
        var element = document.getElementById("cardArea");
        element.appendChild(y);    
    }        
}    
</script>
```

And I have absolutely no idea why, am I miss-using the for loop? or the button? or the `onClick`? or all of them?

I usually use python, and have been able to translate the rest of my program to JavaScript (through sweat, blood, and a few long hours) but this part completely eludes me.

Any feedback at all would be greatly appreciated, my mind has gone completely blank on this.

The `document.write(newFull);` doesn't return any value inside `drawHand()`

One last thing i should mention, this code works fine without the button, but when put inside the button it is completely unresponsive.

**Edit**

As requisted, here are my listeners:

HTML

```
<button onclick="drawCard()" class="hvr-float-shadow">Draw a Card</button>

<button onclick="drawHand()" class="hvr-float-shadow">Draw Hand</button>

<button onclick="" class="hvr-float-shadow">Mulligan</button>
```

And the code that i am using to run the initial loop in a separate java script file.

script.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
 var file = fileInput.files[0];
 var textType = /text.*/;

 if (file.type.match(textType)) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {

    var text = reader.result;

    var lines = text.match(/^.*((\r\n|\n|\r)|$)/gm);

    var index = lines.indexOf('\n');
    lines.splice(index, 99);
    var index2 = lines.indexOf(' ');
    lines.splice(index2, 99);

    var j = 0;

    var fullDeck = [];  

    while (j < lines.length){

        var card = lines[j];

        var cardNumber = card.match(/[0-9]+/g);
        var cardlist = card.match(/[a-zA-Z ]+/g);


        j =j + 1;
        i = 0
        while (i < Number(cardNumber)){
            fullDeck.push(cardlist);
            i = i + 1
        }



    }

    var newFull = fullDeck.slice();
    var k = 0;  
    for (k = 0; k < 7; k++) {

            var randomCard = Math.floor((Math.random() * newFull.length) + 1);

            chosenCard = newFull[randomCard];
            var chosenCardString = String(chosenCard);
            var randomIndex = newFull.indexOf(chosenCard);

            newFull.splice(randomIndex, 1);

            var imageLocation = 'Images/' + chosenCardString.replace(/ /g, '') + '.png';

            var y = document.createElement("IMG");
            y.setAttribute("src", imageLocation);
            y.setAttribute("alt", chosenCard);
            document.body.appendChild(y);
            var element = document.getElementById("cardArea");
            element.appendChild(y);



    }     
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File Loaded!" 


  }

    reader.readAsText(file);

} else {
  fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
}
});
}
```

**/Edit**

Comment: What do you mean *inside the button*? Can you show us your listener code? As far as `document.write` not showing anything, can you also show us where you initialize the `fullDeck` variable?

Comment: You don't need the `document.body.appendChild(y)`, since you are already appending it to "cardArea".

Comment: I'll add the rest of the code when I finish work in the morning, sorry I wasn't sure what was relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When `document.write()` is used AFTER the page has finished loading, it first clears the current document and then writes to a new empty document - wiping out all prior content.  So, this line:

```
document.write(newFull);
```

is probably causing you a major problem.

Since that is almost never what you want, `document.write()` should not be used in event handlers that run after the page is loaded.  Instead, you should use regular DOM manipulation functions that modify the current DOM directly.

Comment: Thanks for the information, its useful to know when it runs, i was mainly using `document.write()` for troubleshooting, similarly to how i would use `print()` in python. Is there a better way to do this?  I don't usually code in java script.

Comment: @MattCornell - Use `console.log()` and open the debug console to see the output.

Comment: That helps a lot thanks, I am going to try having another go at this in a second but i am not sure that i have used the listeners correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out this was an issue with my variables being local instead of global, absolutely silly mistake. I was trying to use a variable not realizing that `var` would make it local only. I changed my `fullDeck` variable to global like so:

Local Variable:

`var fullDeck = []`

Global variable:

`fullDeck = []`

Probably obvious to many but i wanted to post it incase anyone else came across this kind of problem.